# How do I use scala and scalatest to see if a list contains an object with a field matching a specific value

Tags: scala, scalatest

I would like my test to check that a list of object contains an object with a specific matching field. For example:

```
class ListTest extends ScalaTesting {
    class MyData(val one:Int, val two:Int) {
    }

    val listOfMyData = List(new MyData(1,2), new MyData(3,4)

    listOfMyData should contain (a mydata object with field two matching 4)
}
```

Obviously this doesn't actually work

Comment: Just a note, with specs2 you can write `list must contain((data: MyData) => data.two === 4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever i have to assert fields of list, I do **`.map` over the list and compare the value.**

eg.

```
class SomeSpecs extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("contains values") {

    case class MyData(field1: Int, field2: Int)

    List(new MyData(1,2), new MyData(3,4)).map(_.field2) should contain (4)
  }
}
```

And `List(new MyData(1,2), new MyData(3,9)).map(_.field2) should contain (4)` will throw error `List(2, 9) did not contain element 4`.

**The second approach would be**

```
List(new MyData(1, 2), new MyData(3, 9)).count(_.field2 == 4) > 0 shouldBe true
// or
List(new MyData(1, 2), new MyData(3, 4)).count(_.field2 == 4) should be > 0
```

but the thing I don't like about this is its true or false. eg. `List(new MyData(1, 2), new MyData(3, 11)).count(_.field2 == 4) shouldBe true` throws error `false was not equal to true`

while the first approach tells me more than that as it gives what is the input data and what is expected. At least I find first approach helpful while refactoring tests.

**Third approach can be**

```
List(new MyData(1, 9), new MyData(3, 4)).filter(_.field2 == 4) should not be empty
```

*But I **WISH** scalatest also had something like
`List(new MyData(1,2), new MyData(3,4)) should contain (MyData(_, 4))`*

Answer (score 3):

How about this `list.map(_.two) should contain (4)`

You can also do `atLeast(1, dataList) should matchPattern MyData(_, 4)`

Comment: The usage of `atLeast` deserve a vote, this is a more expressive way than `list.map should contain`. Sadly there is no `only(Int, ..)` nor `atMost`.

Answer (score 0):

to verify/assert/test that listOfMyData contains MyData with 4 as the value of the *.two attribute, you can either filter the elements which match your filter function here (*.two==4) and then test the length of the filtered list/seq

```
listOfMyData.filter(_.two==4).length > 0
```

or better use find to find the first match (which returns an Optionp[MyData])

```
listOfMyData.find(_.two==4) != None
```

with FunSuite and with/without Matchers

```
class MyDataTestSuite extends FunSuite  with Matchers {

  test("test") {
    case class MyData(one: Int, two: Int)
    val listOfMyData = List(new MyData(1,2), new MyData(3,4))
    listOfMyData.find(_.two==4) should not be None
    // equivalent to
    assert(listOfMyData.find(_.two==4) != None)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer.